# Dynamic creation of form using vuetify

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

HTML code **:**

```
<v-col cols="12" md="4" v-for="(leadObj, i) in lead.data" :key="i" >
      <v-col  v-if="leadObj.inputType !=='select'">
         <v-text-field
            v-model="leadObj.comment"
            :type="leadObj.inputType"
            :counter="50"
            :label="leadObj.field"   
          ></v-text-field>
       </v-col>
      <v-col v-if="leadObj.inputType ==='select'">
            <v-select
               v-model="leadObj.comment"
               :items="leadObj.jsonData"
               item-text="name"
               item-value="value"
               :label="leadObj.field"                              
             ></v-select>
      </v-col>
</v-col>
```

If I print `leadObj` data comes up like this **:**

For `inputType` as text **:**

```
{ "id": 4, "field": "Name", "jsonData": null, "module": "Personal", "moduleName": null, "inputType": "text", "comment": "Maharashtra" },
```

For `inputType` as select **:**

```
{ "id": 5, "field": "Educational Details", "jsonData": [ { "name": "SSC", "value": "SSC", "id": 1 }, { "name": "HSC", "value": "HSC", "id": 2 }, { "name": "Diploma", "value": "Diploma", "id": 3 }, { "name": "Graduate", "value": "Graduate", "id": 4 }, { "name": "Post Graduate", "value": "Post Graduate", "id": 5 } ], "module": "Personal", "moduleName": null, "inputType": "select", "comment": "Graduate"},
```

For `inputType` as radio **:**

```
{ "id": 6, "field": "gender", "jsonData": [ { "name": "Male", "value": "male", "id": 1 }, { "name": "Female", "value": "female", "id": 2 } ], "module": "Personal", "moduleName": null, "inputType": "radio","comment": "", "required": "required" }
```

If `:type="radio"` then radio button are not populating correctly. Does vuetify suppose dynamic creation of fields based on `:type` ? For select I need to add v-select component else it was considering v-text-field in the same way am I suppose to add for radio and other element as well ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @kiran I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that ? I hope that will help you in understanding the use case and will work as per your requirement

Comment: @RohìtJíndal, Yes! it is working perfectly. Thank you so much for taking time to look into it and for your efforts.

Comment: @kiran Np! Glad it works as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I suppose to add for radio and other element as well ?* - Answer is Yes.

For radio buttons, component is `v-radio` but you are using `v-text-field` for all the input types which don't have select. Using of proper component based on `inputType` will resolve the issue.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      lead: {
        data: [{ "id": 4, "field": "Name", "jsonData": null, "module": "Personal", "moduleName": null, "inputType": "text", "comment": "Maharashtra" }, { "id": 5, "field": "Educational Details", "jsonData": [ { "name": "SSC", "value": "SSC", "id": 1 }, { "name": "HSC", "value": "HSC", "id": 2 }, { "name": "Diploma", "value": "Diploma", "id": 3 }, { "name": "Graduate", "value": "Graduate", "id": 4 }, { "name": "Post Graduate", "value": "Post Graduate", "id": 5 } ], "module": "Personal", "moduleName": null, "inputType": "select", "comment": "Graduate"}, { "id": 6, "field": "gender", "jsonData": [ { "name": "Male", "value": "male", "id": 1 }, { "name": "Female", "value": "female", "id": 2 } ], "module": "Personal", "moduleName": null, "inputType": "radio","comment": "male", "required": "required" }]
      },
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>

<div id="app">
  <div data-app v-for="(leadObj, i) in lead.data" :key="i">
    <v-select v-if="leadObj.inputType ==='select'"
               v-model="leadObj.comment"
               :items="leadObj.jsonData"
               item-text="name"
               item-value="value"
               :label="leadObj.field"
             ></v-select>
    <v-text-field v-if="leadObj.inputType ==='text'"
            v-model="leadObj.comment"
            :type="leadObj.inputType"
            :counter="50"
            :label="leadObj.field"
          ></v-text-field>
    <v-radio-group v-if="leadObj.inputType ==='radio'" v-model="leadObj.comment">
      <v-radio
        v-for="r in leadObj.jsonData"
        :key="r.name"
        :label="`${r.name}`"
        :value="r.value"
      ></v-radio>
    </v-radio-group>
  </div>
</div>
```